# Error 21007: status result returned by Apple during in-app subscription restore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We are testing 'restore subscription' using Apple's new in-app subscription model.  The In App Purchase Programming Guide lists 6 status codes that are returned by the Apple server during the restoration/purchase process ("Verifying an Auto-renewable receipt" - page 33/34).
However, the errors start at 21000 and end at 21006. We just tried to restore a subscription and received a status result of 21007. I have googled this error and am not finding any information about what this status result means.
Thank you in advance ....

---

Error 21008 is also another Error response that Apple returns if you point to the wrong production/sandbox server.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do not point your script to the live Apple server when you're testing using the sandbox(!)

Lesson learned. Hope this post helps someone else.

Comment: You should use [https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt](https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt) instead

Answer (score 10):

I just returned from [iOS 5 Tech Talk World Tour 2011](http://developer.apple.com/techtalk/) and the Apple Tech in the In App Purchase session said that the app review process uses the sandbox when reviewing a submitted app and that they would appreciate it if we would check for this error code and **forward the request to the sandbox** if we get this error code.

Error code 21008 was the same issue but for a different IAP.  i.e. consumable versus non-consumable.  I assume the same goes for that code as well.  i.e. to forward to the sandbox if received.

Sounds like this might speed up the review process a little.

From [Validating Receipts with the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store):

> Verify your receipt first with the production URL; then verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. This approach ensures you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is tested, reviewed by App Review, or live in the App Store.

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is late but I figured anyone else come across this question, they would like to know what the proper URL to use.

You should use the: https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt URL to test with the sandbox.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a server-side script that connects to the sandbox or real AppStore server to validate receipts, always try the real server first, and if you get a 21007 status code, fallback to the sandbox server, in order to support both environments when you submit your application for review, as they will test it with a sandboxed user account!

More info in the following post:
[(iOS + StoreKit) Can I detect when I'm in the sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677193/ios-storekit-can-i-detect-when-im-in-the-sandbox)

Comment: This is **slightly wrong**, gang.  (1) go to the real app store. and get a result.  (2) if it is **NOT ZERO**, then (3) ALSO go to the sandbox app store. Do **not** rely on code 21007. The code for wrong server **can be different depending on the type of purchase**. For instance 21008 can also be seen. (And indeed, it could very easily change in the future, etc etc.)  So, simply check for zero.  If it's not zero, try the other server!  It is absolutely harmless trying both servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this also but from Apple's own tests (app is in review) and just received and email from Apple saying the review will take longer.

Perhaps it's some transient  problem with App Store itself.

Comment: I just got rejected because of this. It is strange that they use sandbox accounts during review