# How to tell Apple In App Purchase is a debug testing in backend

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I got a backend server to validate whether an apple in app purchase is genuine or not. Since the purchase is made in the iOS app, the backend has no idea what apple account was used to made the purchase. I am just wondering, is there a way that backend can tell this purchase is made from an debug apple Id which does not involve any real money by interpret the response from apple in app purchase verification.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two different environments. QA and Production. QA can be a local host to simplify things.

If you want to validate receipts on the backend you actually have to post to a different itunes url (sandbox vs buy.itunes) so when you want to test 'sandbox' IAP just make sure your app is pointing to your QA server, as opposed to your production server.

Comment: The general recommended approach is to not have to change your server between production vs. testing/sandbox modes (e.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187231/how-do-i-know-if-an-in-app-purchase-receipt-comes-from-the-sandbox). On your server, first attempt to validate the receipt against the production URL (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt), then if that fails use the sandbox URL (see https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt). See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: As seen here these only apply to auto renewable subscriptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677193/ios-storekit-can-i-detect-when-im-in-the-sandbox if you have a system where the prod simply falls back to sandbox that's great. That being said it's good engineering practice to have a Qa environment so it makes sense to have QA always point to the sandbox url. An alternate idea is to have a configuration based on your xcode scheme where release always points to prod, and debug always points to QA

Comment: Can you find a current reference to this apparent issue about error code 21007? I cannot find it in the Apple docs any more. Also, I think your alternative idea may not work. My understanding is that when Apple tests your *release* app, they test it in the sandbox environment.

Comment: That status code pertains only to auto renewable subscriptions (and is important!) at least according to the docs. The release/debug idea will work since the verification url only changes on the server side (no client side changes are necessary for sandbox vs prod IAP). To be more specific my suggestion is to point 'debug' scheme apps to your QA server and 'release' scheme apps to your prod url. Your prod server should handle prod receipts, not sandbox.

Comment: What do you think about Table 2-1 in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/ValidateAppStoreReceipt.pdf? There appears to be no qualification there that code 21007 is only for auto-renewables. And also, in my experience so far in sandbox testing of IAP's (non-renewable and non-consumable products) I *am* getting code 21007 when I try to validate a sandbox receipt against the production server. Do you have experience indicating that code 21007 is not returned in this manner (e.g., for an app in the app store)?