# After changing sandbox account, Apple IAP restore data is sending same receipts

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am working with IAP Auto renewable subscription. I was testing with one sandbox account after that I have changed sandbox account but for receipt validation I am still getting same receipts.

PS: I have also tried

```
// Hint... handle requestDidFinish delegate method and then use appStoreReceiptURL for receipt data
let request:SKReceiptRefreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil);
request.delegate  = self;
request.start();
```

But it keeps asking iTunes password which is very annoying.

Comment: Which build are you testing; Development, Adhoc or test flight?

Comment: @shoaib Development

Comment: You might find this question and answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677354/8289095

Comment: I have tried calling Refresh request before using reciept but it returns the old reciept for new user.

Answer (score 2):

Try Calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest before you access appStoreReceiptURL;
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest

```
// Hint... handle requestDidFinish delegate method and then use appStoreReceiptURL for receipt data
let request:SKReceiptRefreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil);
request.delegate  = self;
request.start();
```

Comment: it is asking for password every time is there another way?

Comment: @shoaib Any luck with that ? I am facing same kind of issue. I even call refresh reciept but it returns same reciept for different sandbox user.